# neovim api I want to know why the window frame is only drawn on the right side of the screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lua, neovim

## Contents of question

I would like to add a frame to a window I created using the neovim api, but only the right side is displayed as shown in the presented image.What is the cause of this?

## What I tried

1. Experiment by changing style to `'number', 'relativenumber', 'cursorline', 'cursorcolumn', 'foldcolumn', 'spell'
2. Ask a question on ChatGDT

## Reference site

neovim api (section Win_Config Functions): https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#api-window

## What I want to know

I want to draw frames in the four corners of the generated window

## Environment

shell: fish

OS: ubuntu 20.4

Language: lua

neovim version: 0.9.4

## source code

```lua
local M = {}

---##########################################################################
--- show window
---##########################################################################
function M.Find()
  
    local opts = 
    {
        relative = "win",
        width = 20,
        height = 10,
        row = 10,
        col = 10,
        style="minimal",
        border = {"╔", "═" ,"╗", "║", "╝", "═", "╚", "║"}
    }

    local content = {}
    local buffer = vim.api.nvim_create_buf(false,true);
    local float_win = vim.api.nvim_open_win(buffer,true,opts)
    vim.api.nvim_set_current_win(float_win)

end


return M
```

## Current image

[image]